# mod_rewrite style URL replacement in PHP

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I'm looking for a simple solution to rewrite URL in PHP. The customer wants to store them in a database so I can't use mod_rewrite.

Basically I am looking for a PHP solution to make this happen:

```
^/(.*).html ==> /page.$1.html
```

Such PHP code exists? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The whole point of mod_rewrite is to identify which PHP (or HTML) file to run. Once it gets to the PHP file, that process is already over and finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean with your example since it would essentially create a never-ending redirection loop.

```
^/(.*).html ==> /page.$1.html ==> /page.page.$1.html ==> /page.page.page.$1.html ==> etc.
```

I'm assuming since you said you're getting these rules from a database that you want to take specific strings instead of `(.*)`

What you want to do is match whatever you're trying to search for with the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` variable and then do a redirect using PHP. Something like this:

```
foreach ($searches as $string) {
    if (preg_match("@^/$string\.html$@", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
        header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
        header("Location: http://www.yoursite.com/page.$string.html");
    }
}
```